# How to remove a single non unique element from a list or vector in r

Tags: r, vector, unique

What im looking for is a efficient way to remove a single nonunique element.

Say i have the vector:

```
c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4)
```

and i want to remove:

```
c(1,2)
```

such so that the result would be

```
c(1,1,2,3,3,4)
```

Im sure its very simple but im at a loss. Sound out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `match`. Here's the code

```
a <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4)
b <- c(1,2)

a[-match(b, a)]
### [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
```

This works because `match` *only* returns a vector of the positions of **(first)** matches of its first argument in its second.

EDIT: As @Ananda Mahto pointed out, this only works if all elements in `b` are also in `a`. For a more general formula use the following function

```
element_rm <- function(a, b){
  if (any(b%in%a)) return(a[-match(b[b%in%a], a)])
  else return(a)
}
a <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4)
element_rm(a, c(1,2))
##  [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
element_rm(a, c(2,5))
## [1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 4
element_rm(a, 5)
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4
element_rm(a, c(4,4))
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: Ah thanks so much, i completely forgot about that! i was trying to use the apply functions in a crazy way!

Comment: +1, but I would modify it to be something like: `a[-match(which(b %in% a), a)]`. Compare with a scenario where `b <- c(1, 7)` (or some other value that doesn't exist in the input vector). In fact, there should probably be an `ifelse` in there too.